# In Koltin/Java how to force a local project class to be overridden with a class of the same name from a Maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, classpath, dependency-management

I have a class A which exists in package com.A

I want to keep this class as a type-safe place holder and then override it with a class of the same name `com.A` and generic parameterization `A<String>`, which is located in a maven dependency which the project references.

Kotlin code:

so in the main project we have:

```
package com

class A<String>{}
```

and in the dependancy project we have:

```
package com

class A<String>{
     fun extraStuff(){
        // ...
    }
}
```

Currently the project is using the local class only even with the presence of the maven dependency, is there a java trick or possibly a maven feature that will force the overriding of the local class?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not without a lot of hacking at maven. You could use the maven-shade-plugin to do something like that, but this digs deeper into the question of _Why do you want to do this?_

You shouldn't need to define a local version of the class if it's defined in a dependency. Also, I don't think the "generic parameterization" is doing what you think it does. That just defines a generic parameter named `String`, which is completely unrelated to the existing class `String`.

Comment: I want to keep the compiler happy for a framework I'm working on, so how would you use the maven-shade-plugin to do this?

Comment: Oh I should simply extract the class into its own dependancy and just have two separate maven dependancies and reference them separate in each project

Comment: Your question is confusing and like Darth Android I don't understand why you would want to do what you are doing, but from what your code is trying to do I think you are really looking for extensions: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html

Basically you can extend any class within a given scope like this:
`fun A<String>.extraStuff() { /* your code here */ }`

Comment: "I want to keep the compiler happy" --> The class in the dependency should keep the compiler happy; If it doesn't then you're building a different class and it should be named differently.